# Nonstandard Complex Analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

I recently discovered Nonstandard Analysis and am slowly working my way through Kelsier's textbook and Foundations companion.  However while I have found plenty of stuff about real nonstandard analysis I have not been able to discover anything about complex nonstandard analysis.  Would anyone be able to recommend any such resources to add to my reading list once I am done with Kelsier's book?

Comment: While not text books, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900094/nonstandard-complex-numbers), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779900/non-standard-complex-analytic-functions), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117887/complex-numbers-and-nonstandard-analysis) are three MSE references.

Comment: I saw those yeah, but I was hoping for something a bit meatier.